# JSON key file store in databricks secrets

Tags: databricks

Can someone please let me know the process of how I can store a json key file in databricks secrets. This secret key json file stores the values of service account details which I need to interact with Google Drive. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `databricks-cli`.

```
databricks secrets put --scope myscope --key mykey --binary-file ~/path/to/file.json
```